# Align different sized icons with each other (font awesome)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using font awesome to add icons beside my text links. My issue is the spacing is off since the icons are in different sizes.

Bootstrap 4 is being used as well

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
    <span class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-user col-centered pr-3"></i><a href="cards/profile-page.php" class="header-dropdown-links">My Profile</a></span>
    <span class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-file col-centered pr-3  text-center"></i><a href="list-claimed.php" class="header-dropdown-links">My Coupons</a></span>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <span class="dropdown-item"><a href="signout" class="signout">Sign out</a></span>
</div>
```

I can't do the "pr" class since all it does is move everything to the size.

I just would like to have the icons and text to align themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ul and add `fa-ul` provided by fontawsome to make a list of the icons.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>List icons can</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-check-square"></i></span>be used to</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i></span>replace bullets</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-square"></i></span>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to use ul. The other option is to add the fa-fw class as mentioned in the other solution here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fa-fw` for a fixed width. More info check this [link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons).
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xqmeL6t8/1/) is the working code.

Comment: This is the simplest and most elegant solution. I'd have to refactor all my menus if I were to use the ul above. All I had to do here is add a class to each icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use Bootstrapt 4. You can use flex behaviors classes, for detail [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/](http://[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/])

You can add icon and text container's class d-flex align-items OR align-self Bootstrapt 4 classes.

If you dont have much info for `display: flex` , [visit here](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv) this is helpful for your problem.